# How can I show dynamically changing value on background service notification using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, notifications, background

I am trying to show the value scanned from BLE on background service notification even when app is closed. So I used [flutter_background_service] [1](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service) However, I don't know how to show dynamically changing value as it shows on widget. I am in trouble.. Can i ask for your help? Thank you.

```
Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) async {
    if (service is AndroidServiceInstance) {
      if (await service.isForegroundService()) {
        /// OPTIONAL for use custom notification
        /// the notification id must be equals with AndroidConfiguration when you call configure() method.
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
          888,
          'App Name',
          'value: ${}, // <- I want to put value in here.
          const NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
              'my_foreground',
              'MY FOREGROUND SERVICE',
              icon: 'ic_bg_service_small',
              ongoing: true,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly create a new class.

```
class ProjectBackgroundService{}
```

Now let's define the functions that you will use in this class.

The first of these will be the **readyForShared()** function. This function allows us to define and read local variables.

```
`Future<void> readyForShared() async {
   var sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   counterValue = sharedPreferences.getString("yourVariable") ??"0";
 }`
```

Now let's write the function that saves our local variables.

```
Future<void> saveData(String value) async {
  var sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  sharedPreferences.setString("yourVariable", value);
}
```

Now let's write your service function **onStart()**

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void onStart(ServiceInstance service) async {

  // Only available for flutter 3.0.0 and later
  DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();

  // For flutter prior to version 3.0.0
  // We have to register the plugin manually

  SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await preferences.setString("hello", "world");

  /// OPTIONAL when use custom notification
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  if (service is AndroidServiceInstance) {
    service.on('setAsForeground').listen((event) {
      service.setAsForegroundService();
    });

    service.on('setAsBackground').listen((event) {
      service.setAsBackgroundService();
    });
  }

  service.on('stopService').listen((event) {
    service.stopSelf();
  });
    
  // bring to foreground
  Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) async {
    final receivePort = ReceivePort();
    // here we are passing method name and sendPort instance from ReceivePort as listener
    await Isolate.spawn(computationallyExpensiveTask, receivePort.sendPort);

    if (service is AndroidServiceInstance) {
      if (await service.isForegroundService()) {
        //It will listen for isolate function to finish
         receivePort.listen((sum) {
         flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
         888,
         'Title',
         'Description ${DateTime.now()}',
         const NotificationDetails(
         android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
         'my_foreground',
         'MY FOREGROUND SERVICE',
         icon: 'ic_bg_service_small',
         ongoing: true,
         ),
         ),
         );
         });

        var sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        await sharedPreferences.reload(); // Its important
        service.setForegroundNotificationInfo(
          title: "My App Service",
          content: "Updated at ${sharedPreferences.getString("yourVariable") ?? 'no data'}",
        );
      }
    }


    /// you can print
    //if (kDebugMode) {
    //}

    // test using external plugin
    final deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
    String? device;
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      final androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
      device = androidInfo.model;
    }

    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      final iosInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
      device = iosInfo.model;
    }
    service.invoke(
      'update',
      {
        "current_date": '400',
        "device": device,
      },
    );
  });
}
```

Now let's call our service

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
      readyForShared();
      ProjectBackgroundService().onStart();
    });
  }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).